# Bounding "an average"?

Tags: self-study, terminology, mean

I'm doing a practice problem that is about processing orders.

The assumptions are:

"On average 40 orders are received"
"50 orders per day can be processed"

The task is to formulate notions about the probability of the shop being able to fulfill the processing of orders.

But what does "on average" mean here? It cannot mean that "every day 40 orders are processed" since then the probability to succeed in managing those would always be 1.

Perhaps there's some "standard" way of finding out what the "mean deviation" can be? Or the variance?

Specifically I need to find an "upper bound".

Comment: Since it's now clear this is a `self-study` question, please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Such a phrase ("on average 40 orders are received") can either mean that the sample average over some sample is 40 or it means that the long run (i.e. population) average is 40. In this case it means the second one.

It certainly *doesn't* mean "every day 40 orders are processed" (that's not to say that this isn't the case in this instance; it's a possible situation that's consistent with the information -- but so are many other possibilities).

It's telling you about a population quantity (the mean of the distribution of the number of orders received) for the process.

It *could* be that there's little variation in orders received (that they're nearly always close to 40) or it could be that there's a great deal of variation in the orders received (i.e. that the actual number in a day is generally not very close to 40)

Your last sentence isn't clear. From the information given there's no way to infer any information about variation about the mean, such as mean deviation - it could be as low as zero or it could be arbitrarily large.

---

Edit: it now appears that you're asking about how to bound the proportion above 50.

That can be done. Clearly the minimum proportion above 50 is 0.

So what about the *maximum*? You might like to consider

a. the effect on the mean of an element of probability above the mean but close to it

b. the effect on the mean as you shift that element of probability further above the mean

c. that the same effect obtains below the mean

d. that therefore you can "balance" out some probability at some distance above the mean with some other probability at a distance below the mean in such a way that the mean of both contributions is 40.

e. that therefore if you take some distribution with mean 40 that doesn't achieve the maximum, you can move some proportion up and some other proportion down without changing the mean

f. that there's a limit to how far you can move some of the probability down.

without completely giving it away, the result follows from such considerations.

Of course, you *can* apply a theorem -- there's an obvious inequality that applies -- but there's simply no need; the result is obvious from basic considerations.

(Once you work out the answer, the general inequality itself becomes more or less obvious.)

[The OP figured out that the Markov inequality was the relevant one.]

---

Since it appears that it's not obvious to you (you appear to want to jump straight to applying Markov without consideration of just how elementary this is), consider step d. Slightly informally, we have some small amount of probability, $\epsilon$ say, at $40+x$, and some other amount, $\delta$ say, at $40-y$. The remaining $1-\epsilon-\delta$ of probability is distributed (in some fashion) so that its conditional mean is 40. In order for the whole thing to average 40, how would we choose $\epsilon, \delta, x$ and $y$ to get $\epsilon$ of the total probability above 50?

So the contribution to the mean of the $\epsilon$ of probability at $40+x$ is that it adds $x\epsilon$ to the original mean of 40, and the contribution to the mean of the $\delta$ of probability at $40-y$ is that it subtracts $y\delta$ from the mean, and so the total contribution to the mean of those parts is 
$x\epsilon-y\delta$

Note that the constraint that the mean remain 40 imposes one linear restriction on the four quantities.

Note also that

- we want $\delta$ to be as small as possible (why? so we can move more probability in similar steps).
- we want $y$ to be as large as possible (so we can make $\delta$ "count" more in its contribution)
- we want $\epsilon$ to be as big as possible (that's the exercise, after all)
- we therefore want $x$ to be as small as possible given the constraints in the question (to minimize the contribution of the $\epsilon$ to the mean).

So how large can $y$ be? How small can $x$ be? If we fix $\epsilon$, what  must $\delta$ be? Can we make $\epsilon$ larger?

Comment: Well the task is asking for an "upper limit" for "the shop cannot fulfill all orders without overwork". Which implies that something must be known about variance or similar? Given just the information in the starting post.

Comment: Why would you omit vital information from the question?

Comment: In order to not make this seem like "asking help for a practice problem". Feel free to expand, what's relevant about the "upper bound".

Comment: It's easy enough to derive a bound on the probability but you didn't ask about bounding the probability.

Comment: I'm asking about the implications of the wording "on average". Do you mean that there isn't some theorem that "connects" the mean to other concepts such as "some upper bound"?

Comment: Certainly there's a connection between the mean and the amount of distribution that a positive-variable could have above some larger value... but you didn't originally suggest you were seeking anything like that. You asked about *mean deviation* instead.

Comment: Your extended answer is fairly clear, but as this is not a problem asking for simulation. Then what's a "sufficient" upper bound? I think this is asking for Markov's inequality.

Comment: @mavavilj At *no point* in my answer did I suggest "simulation" or even anything like the kind. I was giving a simple sequence of steps to *figure out the answer algebraically* from basic considerations that any novice -- including one that had never seen the Markov inequality before -- could use to arrive at the correct answer to the particular question, and from there, perhaps even arrive at the Markov inequality themselves.

Comment: I was thinking that in order to "break down" the mean one'd need to simulate values "around the mean". Or do you mean that e.g. the deviation of "mean deviation" can be found by hand? If only mean is given?

Comment: I don't understand your comment there. You start with some distribution of values, it doesn't matter what (even everything at 40), and then move some of it further up and some other amount further below 40 in such a way that the mean remains at 40, and repeat the process as much as necessary). Following the sort of elementary reasoning in my answer it soon becomes clear where the probabilities must end up in the limit to get the largest amount anywhere above 50, while you maintain the constraints that the mean is 40 and the lowest possible value is 0. This is a purely algebraic idea.

Comment: Yes but if one wanted to find the theoretical upper bound, then one'd presumably have to simulate a lot of those "variations around the mean".

Comment: @mavavilj No simulation is needed. NONE. I don't know why you're fixated on simulation, it has *nothing whatever* to do with my answer. It's a purely logical argument - one that can be made more formal with little additional effort - from which an algebraic answer can be obtained (and which in turn suggests the outline of  a proof of the Markov inequality). See my additions.

Comment: How can one go through all the possible variations of "these produce mean 40"?

Comment: What's this "adding probabilities" called? I've never heard of this.

Comment: What? We're just looking at expectation -- i.e. $E(X) = \sum_x x.p(x)$ and taking particular $x.p(x)$'s and seeing what happens when we move them about under certain constraints. There's nothing magical going on here, it's just calculating contribution to expectation.

Comment: And how does one know when the upper bound is found?

Comment: Have you tried actually following the argument through? (Once you understand it, it's easy to explain to you why it is the maximum. If you haven't used it to derive the largest proportion you may have trouble seeing why it must be the largest but for example one can look at the original argument and recognize that that the probability-shifting argument can be applied to improve the proportion for any other distribution of values. Or one can, for example, assume there's some other distribution which can beat it, and produce an argument that leads to a contradiction)